# "This is not a valid initialization expression" while using NULL() to initialize pointer

Tags: pointers, types, fortran, derived

I've been trying to migrate a code that was written in the Fortran 90 language from Eclipse to Intel Visual Fortran and I'm having a lot of issues, one of which is the following:

When I type this for my derived type as suggested by everything I've read so far :

`TYPE :: steam_perfor_type
    CHARACTER(8):: name
    DOUBLE PRECISION    ::  TC, HRSG, BC, CC, Pdiff, error, Q, P_TC, P_CC
END TYPE steam_perfor_type 
TYPE(steam_perfor_type),TARGET :: steam_perform
TYPE(steam_perfor_type),POINTER :: perf=>NULL( )`

I get an error "this array or function or substring in invalid in constant expressions" and "this not a valid initialization expression".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It compiles w/o error for gfortran 4.8 and ifort 12.1.1.246.  What version of Intel Visual Fortran are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 11.1.0. I really am clueless as to why it does not compile - maybe I have to check the settings ? I left everything as default because i'm new to the visual studio interface

Comment: Do you have a newer version of IVF to test against?  This might be a bug/issue with 11.1.

Comment: I have a buddy that has another version, i'll try it out and get back to you guys

Comment: You can also try asking about this at the Intel developer zone forums, as it is frequented by the compiler devs and someone will likely know about this issue.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows

Comment: Make sure that the name NULL hasn't been "overridden" by a symbol pulled in from a module by a USE statement.  For example - the modules for the Windows API have their own particular definition of the name NULL.  Initialization of a pointer to NULL in this manner is F95.

Comment: I have the same error on another version of IVF, I'll check right now if NULL has been overriden

Comment: I have indeed a module that is calling DFWINTY which is what might be messing my NULL() statement. I'm looking into the issue right now, though I have no idea where to begin with because the module using DFWINTY is a file from a software called FluidProp.

Comment: Hey guys, just here to tell you that after I put all the declaration in another module everything compiled fine. For some reason I couldn't declare and initialize types and pointers in the same module. Everything is good now, many thanks !